# Why reflection doesn't find method?

Tags: java, class, reflection, types, methods

```
public class Test1<Type>
{
    public Type getCompositeMessage(Type... strings)
    {
        Type val = (Type) "";

        for (Type str : strings) {
            val = (Type) ((String)val + (String)str);
        }
        return val;
    }
}
```

Retrieving method:

```
try
{
    Class<?> c = Class.forName("test1.Test1");
    Method[] allMethods = c.getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method m : allMethods) {
        String mname = m.getName();
        System.out.println(mname);
    }

    Method m = c.getMethod("getCompositeMessage");
    m.setAccessible(true);
    Object o = m.invoke(c, "777777777777777777777777");
    System.out.println(m);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output:

```
getCompositeMessage
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: test1.Test1.getCompositeMessage()
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
at test1.Main.main(Main.java:25)
```

But name of method is exactly the same! Why I receive NoSuchMethodException ?
thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After you fixed the misspelling, you are still looking for the wrong method:

The method is defined as:

```
getCompositeMessage(Type... strings)
```

but you are looking for

```
getCompositeMessage()
```

without parameters.

You need to use:

```
c.getMethod("getCompositeMessage", Object[].class);
```

The next problem will be the call to invoke(), you are passing the class references in stead of the object on which the method should be called.

The next bug is that you are not passing the correct arguments to the function:

```
 Object o = m.invoke(new Test1<String>(), new Object[] {
          new String[] {"777777777777777777777777"}});
```

And the next problem is that you want output the result of the method instead of the method-object in the following line:

```
System.out.println(o);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find it using

```
Test1.class.getDeclaredMethod("getCompositeMessage", Type[].class);
```

(that would be true if `Type` were a class or interface, since it's a generic parameter you are looking for this:)

```
Test1.class.getDeclaredMethod("getCompositeMessage", (Object) Object[].class);
```

And the error you are getting results from the fact that the first parameter needs to be an instance, not the class Object.

wrong:

```
Object o = m.invoke(c /* c is a class Object, but it must be an instance */,
                    "777777777777777777777777" /* this must be an array */);
```

right:

```
Type1<String> t = new Type1<String>();
Object o = m.invoke(t, new Object[]{"foo", "bar"};
```

Comment: Type[].class is illegal because of the way generics work in Java.

Comment: @HendrikBrummermann Oh, sorry, hadn't realized that Type was a generic parameter

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at test1.Main.main(Main.java:27)

Comment: AFAIK it needs add parameters of method - but in this case it is Generic. Object or Object[] .class don't work.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at test1.Main.main(Main.java:29)

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd, java gets confused about the varargs in the called method and the invoke()-method.  You either need to cast the Object[] to object (so that the vararg version of invoke() is used, or put that array into another Object[] array so that the old style invoke() is used.